# Goodness of fit (Kolmogorov-Smirnov) test for a time series?

Tags: time-series, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

This is a somewhat basic question, I guess. I have a sequence of random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ that I believe to be i.i.d. uniform on $[0,1]$. Being i.i.d. uniform corresponds to my model predicting the correct distribution for $P(Y_k\mid Y_{1:k-1})$ for some time series $Y$. I can test that by, say, applying the Kolmogorov-Smirnov or the Anderson-Darling test.

However, there is a type of dependence that I want to check: all together they might have a uniform ecdf, but, $X_1,\ldots,X_{n/2}$ and $X_{n/2+1},\ldots,X_n$ separately might not. But if I apply the KS test to each half, the result will not be independent from the statistic generated by the KS test for the whole sequence.

Furthermore, if I apply the KS test to each window $X_k,\ldots,X_{k+m}$, and get a function $k\mapsto \text{p-value}$, $k=1,\ldots,n$, I can check visually whether there are intervals where KS says they are not uniform. But there are $n-m$ tests for each $k$, so they are very much not independent of each other, so this isn't very sound.

What goodness-of-fit test should I use here? How do I justify this procedure properly? Should I be doing this differently? Which textbooks/articles do I need to read?

Comment: This is a nice idea and it can readily be carried out by simulating the null distribution.  But windows of such sequences can [look remarkably different from the sequences themselves](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38067).  Moreover, the KS test (as well as most distribution tests) is remarkably powerful.  Thus you're almost guaranteed to find extremely low p-values for some windows somewhere in the sequence.  I suspect you would get more out of choosing a small number of appropriate tests in advance instead of conducting such a large number of interdependent tests.

Comment: @whuber Shouldn't the windows' p-values be uniformly distributed, so that I can adjust for the number of windows I have? I am not even sure how to tell if a given test would work for me, or what I should check about it. What if I look at something like the length of the longest run of windows with p-values $<0.5$ (assuming the window length is fixed at something reasonable).